# "grep -Ff file1 file2" prints all the lines of file2 instead of only the ones that contain words from file1

Tags: grep

I have two files, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

In `file1.txt` I have 4 thousand lines of single string words and in `file2.txt` I have 498 sentences.

I want to `grep` `file2` with the contents in `file1` and if that string from `file1` is found in `file2` print the match.

I have tried `grep -f` and `grep -Ff`, but all it does it print the contents of the files.

file1.txt

```
something
somthingelse
maybe
ok
yes
```

file2.txt

```
Hello there how are you
Here is another line ok
Nothing to see here maybe
Nope not here
yes
```

Expected output

```
Here is another line ok
Nothing to see here maybe
yes



 wc -l file1.txt file2.txt
 4000 file1.txt
  498 file2.txt
 4498 total
```

Comment: How is `grep -F -f file1.csv file2.csv` not solving your issue?

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output that reproduces your problem so we can copy/paste to test with it.

Comment: as i said grep -Ff just prints everything from file2

Comment: Understood. [edit] your question to **show** us an example that we can use to reproduce that behavior. My best guess right now is that `file2` is a single line and always matches at least 1 string from `file1` but until you show us an example all we can do is guess. There's also an excellent chance that by trying to create such a minimal example you'll figure out what the problem is yourself.

Comment: Neither the `file1` nor the `file2` you posted are CSVs so are they REALLY representative of your real data? If so, why do you call them CSVs? If not, please fix your example. When you run `grep -Ff file1.cs file2.csv` **using the 2 files you posted** do you really get the full contents of `file2.csv` printed on your screen? If so please copy/paste the command you're running and it's output from your terminal into your question so we can see it.

Comment: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/118699-need-compare-values-two-csv-files.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393568/compare-2-csv-files-using-shellscript-and-output-the-difference-in-a-new-csv-fil

Comment: I tested `grep -F -f file1.csv file2.csv` on the exact example you gave and it gives the expected output.

Run `wc -l file1.csv file2.csv` to make sure it's not a newline problem.

Comment: Regarding `4000 file1.txt` - the `file1` in your question is **not** 4000 lines long. We don't care about files other than the minimal example you provide in your question for us to copy/paste to test with, dont post results related to some other file(s) that we can't see as that's not useful and just obscures the real problem.

Comment: I cant reproduce with a file I just make up. But if I have a 2 CSV files and take the contents from each and then paste to a txt file and then run that command it just prints everything. I think maybe it does now know what it a start of a line and what is a finish of a line perhaps

Comment: Without seeing what your files that have the problem contain we really can't help you any more. Divide and conquer: Take your existing files. Cut each in half. Do you still have the problem? If yes cut them in half again, if no start over deleting the other half of each file. Repeat til you identify a line or 2 in each file causing the problem. Change the proprietary data to values you make up. If you still have the problem then post THAT as your example here. If you don't then choose other values and repeat til you do.

Answer (score 4):

Check for an empty line in `file1` as, if present, the null string contained on that line would match every line in `file2`. With an empty line in `file1`

```
$ cat file1
something
somthingelse
maybe

ok
yes
```

```
$ grep -Ff file1 file2
Hello there how are you
Here is another line ok
Nothing to see here maybe
Nope not here
yes
```

A line containing a single space character would produce the same output as that would match all of the lines that aren't already matched by the `yes` line given the above input.

If both those files are in MSDOS text format with CRLF delimiters as is common for CSVs, one line with only that CR character (an empty line on MSDOS/Windows but a line containing  one control  character on Unix), would also do it.

You could filter out the empty or blank lines of `file1` before using with:

```
grep '[^[:space:]]' file1 | grep -Ff - file2
```

If they are MSDOS files, you'd likely also want to remove those CRs from `file1` as otherwise a `word<CR>` in `file1` would only be found in `file2` if at the end of the line:

```
<file1 dos2unix | grep '[^[:space:]]' | grep -Ff - file2
```

Comment: Nope, no blank I confirmed using sed ---- sed -i '/^$/d' file1.txt and done the same for file2

Comment: That sed command wouldn't remove a line containing a blank char and that would have the same effect on the posted example. Please do what I asked in [my earlier comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689940/extract-lines-from-one-file-containing-words-listed-in-another-file/689948?noredirect=1#comment1304651_689940)

Comment: it contains classified information so no I cant

Comment: I didn't say post your real data, no-one posts their real data, I said create and post a minimal example that reproduces your problem and show the result of running `grep -Ff file1 file2` using that example so we can see that it does reproduce the problem as you describe so we don't waste time trying to debug something that doesnt actually have the problem you want help with (which you didn't do yet).

Comment: I cant reproduce with a file I just make up. But if I have a 2 CSV files and take the contents from each and then paste to a txt file and then run that command it just prints everything. I think maybe it does now know what it a start of a line and what is a finish of a line perhaps

Answer (score 2):

Besides the empty / blank lines and CRLF issues mentioned by Ed, this kind of problem could also happen if there are NUL bytes in `file1`, for instance because the file is encoded in UTF-16 or UTF-16LE / UTF-16BE and your `grep` doesn't support NULs in its input (text files on Unix cannot contain NUL bytes, UTF-16 encoded text can not be processed by text utilities and UTF-16 cannot be the codeset used in a Unix locale).

For instance a `abc<newline>` `file1` encoded in UTF-16BE would contain bytes 0x00 0x61 0x00 0x62 0x00 0x63 0x00 0x0a, and for Unix, that's `<NUL>a<NUL>b<NUL>c<NUL><newline>`. `grep` implementations written in C and that have not been updated to support input with NULs, would read that line into a buffer, and if treated as a C string would be considered an empty string as C strings are NUL-delimited.

For instance with busybox `grep`:

```
$ echo abc | iconv -t UTF-16BE | busybox grep -Ff - <(echo whatever)
whatever
```

If encoded in UTF-16LE (0x61 0x00 0x62 0x00 0x63 0x00 0x0a 0x00), it would be the same as it would consider there's a second line containing just a NUL.

In that case, even with a `grep` implementation that doesn't choke on NULs, you'd also get a match on every line if `file2` was also encoded in UTF-16, as you'd then be effectively looking for NUL bytes in `file2`

You can check whether a file contains NULs with:

```
tr -cd '\0' < file1 | wc -c
```

Which counts them. You can get a clue as to whether it's UTF-16 encode by looking at the values of the first few bytes with `od -vAd -tc -tx1 | head` for instance.

- normal:

  ```
  $ echo abc | od -vAd -tc -tx1 | head
  0000000   a   b   c  \n
           61  62  63  0a
  0000004
  ```
- UTF-16 (with BOM):

  ```
  $ echo abc | iconv -t UTF-16 | od -vAd -tc -tx1 | head
  0000000 377 376   a  \0   b  \0   c  \0  \n  \0
           ff  fe  61  00  62  00  63  00  0a  00
  0000010
  ```
- UTF-16LE (little-endian):

  ```
  $ echo abc | iconv -t UTF-16LE | od -vAd -tc -tx1 | head
  0000000   a  \0   b  \0   c  \0  \n  \0
           61  00  62  00  63  00  0a  00
  0000008
  ```
- UTF-16BE (big-endian)

  ```
  $ echo abc | iconv -t UTF-16BE | od -vAd -tc -tx1 | head
  0000000  \0   a  \0   b  \0   c  \0  \n
           00  61  00  62  00  63  00  0a
  0000008
  ```

You can fix them by using `iconv -f UTF-16LE < file1.csv > file1.unix.csv` for instance.

If those are MSDOS / Windows files, `dos2unix` can also do the conversion from UTF-16 in addition to fixing all the other issues with MS Windows files. For UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE, you'll need to pass some `--assume-utf16le` or `--assume-utf16be` to tell it which it is.

Answer (score -1):

Issue was down to the file with the strings contain SS - This was picking up EVERYTHING

Comment: I don't know what that means. Could you please [edit] your answer to clarify?

Comment: If the pattern file contained the string `SS`, that pattern would _not_ match any of the lines in the file you show.